# Rails 3 Serving old assets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in development and can't seem to get my updated assets to be served.  What I've tried:

Disabling Cache
rake tmp:clear

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to flush your browser cache, set HTTP headers correctly and version control where possible using unique URLs for your assets - lessons I wish I had learnt a long time ago!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake rake:assets:precompile`